# Deleting certain text in a textfile with batch

Tags: batch-file, search, text

There is the Analysis.txt file from which i need all rows containing "< Path >TEXT< /Path >" and < Channel >1< /Channel>. I have done it like this:

```
FOR /F %%i in (Analysis\Analysis.gla) do (
  echo %%i >> Analysis.txt
)

::////Findet Alle Dateinamen in Analysis
for /f %%a IN ('type "Analysis.txt" ^| findstr /i "<Path>" 2^>nul') DO echo 
%%a >> Path.txt
::////Findet den dazugehörigen Channel
for /f %%a IN ('type "Analysis.txt" ^| findstr /i "<Channel>" 2^>nul') DO 
echo %%a >> Channel.txt
```

Now everything is sorted. But I only need the elements between the < Path > and < / Path >.

So my Question is can i delete < Path > and < / Path > before saving them to another .txt or can i just read the element between these out and save it to a variable.

The endresult should get the first row of Path.txt and Channel.txt and combine them.

Greetings,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, for lack of information otherwise (like example lines, for instance) that the required text is all on  the one physical line and the line has no preceding whitespace characters,

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=><" %%a IN ('type "Analysis.txt" ^| findstr /i "<Path>" 2^>nul') DO echo %%a >> Path.txt
```

should work. If there is whitespace on the lines, then change the `2` to `3`.

See `for /?` from the prompt for the reasoning - or see thousands of like examples on SO.

(also, `findstr /i "<Path>" "Analysis.txt"` could also be used to avoid the `type` and pipe.)

Comment: Hi Magoo, thanks for the quick response. It works perfectly now. Thank you ^^

Comment: This was my first post on Stackoverflow, how do i set it to solved?

Comment: Click the tick next to the response